# Flutter: Generate access token from Google service account

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, access-token, service-accounts

I'm trying to access my Firbase Realtime Database through the REST API, which has restricted access. In python I'd generate an access token from the Service Account file google-services.json. Like this:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("/PATH_TO_google-service.json")
token = cred.get_access_token().access_token
```

This token is then used to communicate with the Firebase DB REST API.

I'm unable to find a library or a way to do this in Flutter (or Dart library). I looked into `googleapis_auth` and use `ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({...})`, but I couldn't find a way to fetch the access token.

How can I fetch the access token? Is there a specific library for this?

Comment: You can write code to parse the JSON yourself and use the result for your API requests.  I don't believe there is a provided library, since Flutter is meant to run in client app code, and it's a huge security problem for app code to use service account credentials.  Service account should be used on secure backends, as they have privileged access to Google Cloud projects.  Client apps should use Firebase Authentication to sign in the end user and give user-level access.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the access token on the client is relatively easy, but it requires the client to be authenticated (logged in). Once the user has logged in on the flutter app, you should be able to retrieve the accessToken from watching the auth:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .idTokenChanges()
  .listen((String token) {
    if (token == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

[More details here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state).

Then you can validate the idToken on the server with the firebase admin sdk.

You shouldn't be using serviceAccounts in a client (website, mobile app) the reason being; they give **unrestricted access to firebase resources**, the firebase client sdk makes this very difficult anyway. So it's best to only use serviceAccounts on trusted servers that you control.